# Как пишется слово "контр-чек" (элемент в танго)?

Tags: орфография

Вроде бы приставка "контр-" пишется слитно. Но так некрасиво выглядит "контрчек". Да и 4 согласных подряд. Может, такие слова по-английски писать?

Answer (score 1):

Поиск по словарям иностранных слов ничего не дал, видимо, слово употребляется в русской транскрипции не так давно и его написание ещё не устоялось. "Контрчек" действительно не слишком хорошо звучит по-русски, да к тому же омонимичен банковскому термину. В этих условиях считаю оправданным воспользоваться  огласованной формой приставки контр-, как это уже сделано в словах **контрабас**,  **контра-галс**, и писать соответственно контрачек  или контра-чек. На некоторых тематических танцевальных ресурсах этот термин можно наблюдать именно в такой форме, например:

"К сожалению, сегодня тренеры
включают в хореографию только 4 такта
левых флекерлов — недостаточно, чтобы
«разогнаться» — перед тем, как
преждевременно остановить их контра-
чеком, за которым следует убогая
последовательность из 3 или 4 такта
правых флекерлов и далее — в правые
повороты."

Приставка контр- в заимствованных существительных пишется как слитно, так и через дефис: контрреволюция, но контр-адмирал.

Answer (score 0):

Ну поскольку в словарях нет, можете предложить свой вариант. Мне ближе слитное написание, как и у большинства слов с "контр".  А если там "контра" - то через дефис, естественно. Контрабас - это особый случай, тут нет явного противопоставления "басу".

Comment: Хм... Контрапункт, контрафакт, контрагайка... 
Но контра-чек мне кажется яснее, чем контрачек. Форма прозрачнее.

Comment: Давно это контргайка заполучила гласный в промежность?)))).А первые два - это как контрабас, побуквенная калька с импортного.. Я правда, не слишком разбираюсь в этой степистике и её  терминах... Бог его знает, что оно такое, этот контрчек. В банке тут все понятно. Но там и гласного нет "в промежности". Ладно, это все лирика. Я так понимаю, что промежуточный гласный сам по себе ниоткуда не возникает. Только из языка-источника.

Comment: К сожалению, автор вопроса вряд ли ещё навестит нас. Спросил бы, существует ли чек у этого контра-чека. С языком источника засада, скорее всего термин пишется по- разному в основных европейских языках (уже сталкивался с таким по другому поводу).
С контргайкой да, моя ошибка.

Comment: Язык источника, скорее всего, английский, где слова пишутся раздельно - contra check. К сожалению, я эти названия учил на английском, поэтому не знаю русскоязычных эквивалентов и существуют ли они. Check обозначает резкую остановку в ходе исполнения танцевального шага. Contra - частая приставка для обозначения направления движения противоположного основному направлению движения в танце, например, Contra Body Movement.